# Rails, counting months in date range, between date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, range

This has been quite a mission so far. What i am trying to do is find out how many months there are for a date range between two date ranges.. i know i sound like Yoda right now but let me rather show you what i am trying to accomplish.

```
financial_year_2014 = Date.new(2014,6,29)..Date.new(2015,6,30) 
financial_year_2015 = Date.new(2015,6,29)..Date.new(2016,6,30)
```

Now i have a scorecard that awards 1 point per month you are in the `financial_year_2014`, and 2 points per month you are in the `financial_year_2015`

So if your Scorecards `begin_date` and `end_date` both fall within the `financial_year_2014` its easier where you can do something like this

```
#Does date fall in range method
financial_year_2014.include?(scorecard.begin_date..scorecard.end_date)
```

Which would then return true if it fit within that period, then you could count the months with:

```
((scorecard.end_date.year * 12 + scorecard.end_date.month) - (scorecard.begin_date.year * 12 + scorecard.begin_date.month)) * financial_year_2014_points
```

But now what i can't get is if a scorecards begin_date and end_date cross between two financial years, if the `begin_date` was May and the `end_date` was in August. Then you would have 2 Months in the 2014 financial year and 2 months in the 2015 year. You would then be awarded 1 point for each month in 2014 and 2 points for each month in 2015, for a total of 6 in this example.

The `#does date fall in range method` with the above example won't pass either even though 2 months fall within the range.. Any one have an idea to how i could get this done, or if there  is any gem that handles dates and ranges like this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not 100% sure of how your code is set up but I would have just done something like this:

```
if financial_year_2014.include?(scorecard.begin_date..scorecard.end_date) || financial_year_2015.include?(scorecard.begin_date..scorecard.end_date)
  #calculate based on 2014/2015 year only
else
  #calculate based on split between the years
  range_one = scorecard.begin_date..Date.new(2015,6,30)
  range_two = Date.new(2015,6,30)..scorecard.end_date
  #use new ranges to calculate 
end
```

Comment: yeah thats how i have it structured similarly, the problem i am having is with the method that finds the number of months per range that the scorecard can fall in. - if it does fall between the two ranges the financial_year_2014.include? method will return false

Comment: @TheLegend I did just edit my post because I really need to check what I'm typing before I submit. If financial_year_2014 fails and financial_year_2015 fails then it's kicked into the else which builds 2 new ranges that give you easy access to the number of 2014 months and 2015 months

Answer (score 2):

You can check the months within a date range like this:

```
require 'date'
((Date.today - 90)..Date.today).map{|d| [d.month]}.uniq
```

To check if a range include another range you can use this:

```
a = ((Date.today - 90)..Date.today)
b = ((Date.today-10)..(Date.today-5))
(a.to_a & b.to_a).empty? # false if includes
```

Just be aware that it will compare every member of the Range.